# Drawing on a canvas control in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to convert my application to use the MVVM pattern. I currently have a custom canvas object that inherits form the standard canvas object, and overrides the OnRender event.

I am not quite sure how to convert this method to use the MVVM pattern.

Currently, I have an event wired up to different keypresses, to control the canvas and allows the user to scroll. I have gotten the event stuff wired up in MVVM using MvvmLight. I am just unsure about how when the Command fires in the view, that it updates the canvas. Currently there is a method that is called, that tells the control which direction the user has moved. (I basically pass in a location which is the index of an array).

Just not sure what I should be doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with DependencyProperties and using the DependencyProperties OnPropertyChanged Event Callback to update the graphics.

Answer (score -1):

In our team we also have recently converted silverlight project to mvvm pattern. I don't know is it really required for this particular view to have a view model code to do canvas navigation stuff. If it is not I'd rather recommend to leave this code in view. Otherwise you can expose the

```
public Point CurrentCoordinate
```

property and bind to it from view.